# Accept multiple parameters for API in .NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#

Here I get always null.

How would I create an endpoint in .Net Core that would accept two POCO? Using just one object everything works.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Checkout")]
public IActionResult Checkout([FromBody]Order order, [FromBody]Cart cart)
{            
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Combine them as a single object and pass via body.

Comment: You should have one specific Binding Model for this purpose. That model can have as many other objects as you needed, there is no need for multiple objects as action parameters. After you receive your model, you can map them to your domain using some mapping library or map yourself.

Comment: The default for Model Binding is to bind complex parameters from the body of the request. However, only one parameter per action may be bound from body.

So you need to either

    Combine them into one class that just wraps / holds both parameters as properties - and have them bound from the body (as one object)
    Decide which to bind from the body, and which from the route or the query and add the attributes [FromRoute] or [FromQuery] to one, and [FromBody] to the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have two `[FromBody]` parameters, [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1#bind-formatted-data-from-the-request-body) is very clear about this:

> There can be at most one parameter per action decorated with `[FromBody]`. The ASP.NET Core MVC run-time delegates the responsibility of reading the request stream to the formatter. Once the request stream is read for a parameter, it's generally not possible to read the request stream again for binding other `[FromBody]` parameters.

Normally, you would have a Data Transfer Object (DTO) / ViewModel (VM) that contains all the data you need:

```
public class CheckOutViewModel
{
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public Cart Cart { get; set; }
}
```

You would then use that model for binding:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Checkout")]
public IActionResult Checkout([FromBody]CheckOutViewModel checkout)
{            
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Is this the only option? It seems bad to have to create a new class just to receive this call. Can I use other bind method?

Comment: @Alberto The only other way would be to create a custom model binder that reads the body and determines how to de-serialize that body. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1#custom-model-binder-sample) is the official sample for custom binders

Comment: Is it not possible to pass the parameters otherwise? I tried FromForm and send paramenter inside FormObject, but still null

Comment: @Alberto Not as far as I know, those two are the only "formal" path

Answer (score 1):

Well the posted answer says it but I doubt why you need two model at all? One for `Order` and another for `Cart` for `Checkout` process. Rather your `Cart` entity should have the list of `Order` like below

```
public class Cart
{
   public IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Then your endpoint should only accept a `Cart` object rather like

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Checkout")]
public IActionResult Checkout([FromBody]Cart cart)
{            
    return Ok();
}
```